# ERB vs HAML conversion of an if condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I am getting started with HAML and am working on my converting my first file.
The ostensibly correct omission of the "- end":

```
- if current_user
= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user.id)
= link_to 'Logout', logout_path
- else
= link_to 'Register', new_user_path
= link_to 'Login', login_path
```

gets me:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:28: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:30: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

While the logical

```
- if current_user
= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user.id)
= link_to 'Logout', logout_path
- else
= link_to 'Register', new_user_path
= link_to 'Login', login_path
- end
```

gets me:

```
You don't need to use "- end" in Haml. Use indentation instead:
- if foo?
  %strong Foo!
- else
  Not foo.
```

How do I get this conditional statement working in HAML?

Comment: You have the answer in your question .... The error message tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

HAML is indentation based, and the parser can be tricky.  Replace

```
- if current_user
= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user.id)
= link_to 'Logout', logout_path
- else
= link_to 'Register', new_user_path
= link_to 'Login', login_path
```

with

```
- if current_user
  = link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user.id)
  = link_to 'Logout', logout_path
- else
  = link_to 'Register', new_user_path
  = link_to 'Login', login_path
```

and give it a try.  Notice how the indentation changed on the link_to lines.

Comment: "Inconsistent indentation: 5 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces."

It didn't like it. :(

Comment: You're indenting something too many spaces - or too few. Can you post your entire template?

Comment: I took another look at the spacing and I think you were right. I think I fixed the indenting but now I am getting this:

/app/models/user_session.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 ^
/app/models/user_session.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 ^
/app/models/user_session.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
                                              ^
What am I missing?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be related to Haml. It sounds like you've somehow accidentally put HTML into a model class file.

Comment: @Chuck: HAML isn't used for models, it's used for Views.
@sleepycat: You have HTML in your HAML file.  Please do some further reading into HAML and find some examples.

Comment: Actually, as far fetched as it was, Chuck nailed it. I had tried to save a model file from github and for some reason just got a bunch of html instead of any ruby code. What a mess!
The HAML stuff in the views was a little messed up too but I sorted it out with the tips you guys gave. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3):

```
- if current_user
  = link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user.id)
  = link_to 'Logout', logout_path
- else
  = link_to 'Register', new_user_path
  = link_to 'Login', login_path
```

Answer (score 1):

for more  information about haml  files   vist

http://rubyonrails-tutor.blogspot.com/2010/02/hamltutorial-for-rails-developers.html